# Ubuntu 14.04 suddenly became slow

Tags: 14.04

I have i3 third generation and 6 GB of ram. My system suddenly became very slow. Restarting didn't help.

After doing some debuging I found that there are few processes which are eating crazy amount of RAM and that's why the system is acting slow. I tried killing those processes but they spawn back. All of them are system processes. Any ideas guys? Here is the output for htop

[image: Uploading this image took me around 3 minutes]